# How can I link a postgreSQL database created with the command line to pgAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am creating a Rails project with a postgresql database. I am referring to this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-ruby-on-rails-project-with-a-react-frontend

In the guide, you are to create a database with **rails db:create**, and modify the database.yml file to accept the permissions of a new role they have you make. Anyways, I would like to be able to use this database with pgAdmin to help me with organizing/visualizing the tables. How do I connect them? Do I have to add a new server to pgAdmin for the command line created database to show up? I am new to both rails and postgresql so sorry if this is a basic question.

Comment: Where is postgres installed? You need to add that server to pgadmin to manage it.

Comment: I used the EDB installer to install postgres with pgAdmin. Later when following the aforementioned tutorial I had to install with brew so it could work. Right now in pgAdmin it shows the localhost 'PostgrSQL 12' server so im not sure what the other server would be to add.

Comment: What OS are you running? Did you uninstall the EDB server? If you click on  the 'PostgreSQL 12'  server do you see the database you created?